# crontab from rrule

Tags: cron, icalendar

I have to parse a rrule (from iCal protocol) to a Quartz cron expression.
In a rrule (recurrence rule) there's the possibility to specify the day of the year.

I am looking for a cron expression like 'every 200th day in year'.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

0 0 12 18 7 ? 2012/4

0 0 12 19 7 ? 2013/4

0 0 12 19 7 ? 2014/4

0 0 12 19 7 ? 2015/4